# How to prevent kendo grid reload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, grid

I have two kendo grids (A, B) ...B its loaded by clicking in A and the its data source its loaded by a property of selected row in A ..

A.accounts

```
dataSource: {
    data: this.gridA.dataItem(this.gridA.select()),
},
```

My problem its that in B I have to change a property using  the grid, but when the property its changed the grid its reloaded and if i have 1000 rows when I change the property in the grid (anyrow, 999 i.e), the scroll back to the beginning
...I have read and try to understand it, but a can't fix it... according to the official documentation, the row selected by

```
var row = this.gridApprovals.select();
var caBean = this.gridApprovals.dataItem(row);
```

Its a ObservableObject, so, when I try to change a property, some method (of ObservableOject) it's making this behaviour, and the grid its reloaded, its iterating every data source item...

EDITED:
I forgot to mention.. its important keep the relation between the changes of the B grid and its relation in A slection..
Here is a Dojo Project http://dojo.telerik.com/uYemI/2

Comment: You need to at least provide your grid definition.  Better yet, provide a link to a Kendo Dojo example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: thanks.. i have do it.... here is the link http://dojo.telerik.com/uYemI/2

Comment: I don't really know how to fix it yet but it is the k-rebind="carsGridOptions" that is causing it...when the editCell fires, this attribute causes the k-rebind to fire so the setGridOptions fires which rebinds the whole datasource(and resets the grid).  You need to find a way to just push the new data into the grid without using the k-rebind(which fires on edit for some reason).  So essentially, every editCell causes the grid to reinit its dataSource(through k-rebind mapping) which causes a fresh re-read.  We need to not do that...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/aNije

I removed the k-rebind attribute and instead wire up the dataSource inside your setCarsGrid() method:

```
$scope.setCarsGrid = function() {
            var row = this.brandGrid.select();
            var brand = this.brandGrid.dataItem(row);
                            var brandObj=brand.toJSON();

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
              data: brand.cars,
              schema:{
                model:{
                  fields:{
                    id:{editable:false},
                    model:{editable:false},
                    color:{type:"string"}
                  }
                },
                parse: function(response) {
                  $.each(response, function(idx, elem) {
                    elem.id = elem.id+10;
                    //if you put a break point here, every time you try to edit 'color' field.. will be stop because datasourse is iterated again 
                    console.log("Grid has been reloaded and the editable field 'color' can be edited :'( the id property has been added +10")
                  });

                  return response;
                }                                    
              }
            });

          // This first time this is called, the carsGrid has not been initialized, so it doesn't exist.
          // But subsequent times, we just need to set the new datasource.
          if (this.carsGrid) {
            this.carsGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
          }

            $scope.carsGridOptions = {
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    selectable:true,
                    editable: true,
                    columns: [{
                        field: "id",
                        },{
                        field: "model",
                        },{
                        field: "color",
                    }]
                };                     

        }
```

Essentially, I am just separating initialization of the GRID from the setting of the grid's DATASOURCE.
The first time through, you set up the grid options AND set the dataSource and then subsequent times through, we just set the grid to the new dataSource.

This avoids the k-rebind behaviour...which I believe is documented: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-update-upon-option-changes

> This approach is not suitable for dataBound widgets because those widgets are   recreated on each change of their data—for example, after paging of the Grid.

Note, I don't really know angular so there may be a better way to organize this code, but it works.

Comment: it look good, but in my project doesn't work, i think its my kendo version, I forgot to set the version in dojo.. im using Kendo UI 2015 Q2 .. and look like if i could not set dataSource in this way... humm

Comment: Hi.. after some experiments I have used this.carsGrid.setOptions, here is a dojo with mi final code... Thanks @The Dread Pirate Stephen for your help....
http://dojo.telerik.com/@alfonsomonroyiv/oneJA